# Mixed model starting values for lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to fit a mixed model using the `lmer` function from the `lme4` package. However, I do not understand what should be input to the `start` parameter.
My purpose is to use a simple linear regression to use the coefficients estimated there as starting values to the mixed model.

Lets say that my model is the following:

```
linear_model = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data)
coef = summary(linear_model)$coefficients[- 1, 1] #I remove the intercept
result = lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, start = coef)
```

This example is an oversimplified version of what I am doing since I won't be able to share my data.

Then I get the following kind of error:

```
Error during wrapup: incorrect number of theta components (!=105) #105 is the value I get from the real regression I am trying to fit.
```

I have tried many different solutions, trying to provide a list and name those values `theta` like I saw suggested on some forums.

Also the Github code test whether the length is appropriate but I cant find to what it refers to:

```
# Assign the start value to theta
if (is.numeric(start)) {
        theta <- start
}

# Check the length of theta
length(theta)!=length(pred$theta)
```

However I can't find where `pred$theta` is defined and so I don't understand where that value `105` is coming from.

Any help ?

Comment: It will provide a starting value if you don't.  Just leave it out.

Comment: I want to provide one in order to speed up the computation. The idea was to run a linear regression and use the coefficients obtained as the starting values.

Comment: It already does computations internally to get good starting values particularly if your only mixed terms are of the form 1|x.  Note that there is a lme4 vignette on performance.

Comment: It is rather of the shape y ~ x | x. How does it decides which starting values to use ?

Comment: You may be better off trying to play with the stoppiong criteria rather than the starting values.  Again, see the vignette.

Answer (score 7):

A few points:

- `lmer` doesn't in fact fit any of the fixed-effect coefficients explicitly; these are profiled out so that they are solved for implicitly at each step of the nonlinear estimation process. The estimation involves only a nonlinear search over the variance-covariance parameters. This is detailed (rather technically) in one of the [lme4 vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) (eqs. 30-31, p. 15).  Thus providing starting values for the fixed-effect coefficients is impossible, and useless ...
- `glmer` *does* fit fixed-effects coefficients explicitly as part of the nonlinear optimization (as @G.Grothendieck discusses in comments), if `nAGQ>0` ...
- it's admittedly rather obscure, but the starting values for the `theta` parameters (the only ones that are explicitly optimized in `lmer` fits) are 0 for the off-diagonal elements of the Cholesky factor, 1 for the diagonal elements: this is coded [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/utilities.R#L184)

```
   ll$theta[] <- is.finite(ll$lower) # initial values of theta are 0 off-diagonal, 1 on
```

... where you need to know further that, upstream, the values of the `lower` vector have been coded so that elements of the `theta` vector corresponding to diagonal elements have a lower bound of 0, off-diagonal elements have a lower bound of `-Inf`; this is equivalent to starting with an identity matrix for the *scaled* variance-covariance matrix (i.e., the variance-covariance matrix of the random-effects parameters divided by the residual variance), or a random-effects variance-covariance matrix of (sigma^2 I).

If you have several random effects and big variance-covariance matrices for each, things can get a little hairy. If you want to recover the starting values that `lmer` will use by default you can use `lFormula()` as follows:

```
library(lme4)
ff <- lFormula(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
(lwr <- ff$reTrms$lower)
## [1]    0 -Inf    0
ifelse(lwr==0,1,0)  ## starting values
## [1] 1 0 1
```

For this model, we have a single 2x2 random-effects variance-covariance matrix. The `theta` parameters correspond to the lower-triangle Cholesky factor of this matrix, in column-wise order, so the first and third elements are diagonal, and the second element is off-diagonal.

- The fact that you have 105 `theta` parameters worries me; fitting such a large random-effects model will be extremely slow and take an enormous amount of data to fit reliably. (If you *know* your model makes sense and you have enough data you might want to look into faster options, such as using Doug Bates's `MixedModels` package for Julia or *possibly* `glmmTMB`, which might scale better than `lme4` for problems with large `theta` vectors ...)
- your model formula, `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x1 + x2 + x3`, seems very odd.  I can't figure out any context in which it would make sense to have the *same* variables as random-effect terms and grouping variables in the same model!

Comment: Let `y` be the rating a person `i` gives to a product that as a combination of attributes `x` denoted by dummies `x1`, `x2`, `x3`. We want to capture the coefficients associated to those dummies, taking into account that every person `i` do not have the exact same rating pattern and some respondant will have very few product that they will rate making it hard using their response alone to identify their own pattern.

Comment: estimating the among-person variation in response to predictors `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` (as well as the population-average responses) would be specified by the formula `y~x1+x2+x3+ (x1+x2+x3|i)` ...

Comment: Yes sorry, that is actually what I do. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: OK.  It's still going to be very challenging to fit a 14*14 variance-covariance matrix ... how many subjects, how many total obs?

Comment: On the example I gave you, we have 735 observations with 50 respondants and 13 dummies used to calibrate the model. But consider it just an example since we are developping a tool that people will be using, providing there own data. So we won't have any control on the number of respondants, observations or predictors.

Comment: I can almost guarantee you that estimating a 14x14 variance-covariance matrix from (approximately) that number of respondents and total observations won't work.  You could consider putting together a compound-symmetric or block-compound-symmetric model in `nlme` ...